# How to wait for the twilio callback until it changes from TBD to the actual price?

Tags: python, django, twilio

I am trying to wait for the callback after the price is generated because it comes back as None and my model is Float field, so it throws a value error(ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'one').

To counter this, I thought of using the sleep function. Unfortunately, it did not work when I asked the callback to sleep for 10 sec, so to be safe I asked the callback to sleep for 80 sec.

Doing this I realised that Twilio has a timeout of 10 sec, so I got an error(11205 HTTP connection failure)

How do I fix this?

#### views.py

```py
@login_required
def start_campaign(request, campaign_id):

    # send_campaign.apply_async(args[])
    try:
        campaign = Campaign.objects.get(pk=campaign_id)
        campaign.status = 'started'
        campaign.save()
        account_sid = 'XXX'
        auth_token = 'XXX'
        client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

        phone_numbers = Contact.objects.filter(phone_book=campaign.phone_book)
        xml_url = 'http://XXX.ngrok.io/call-center/assets/' + str(campaign_id)
        callback_url = 'http://XXX.ngrok.io/call-center/events/' + str(campaign_id)

        for phone_number in phone_numbers:

            call = client.calls.create(
                method='GET',
                status_callback=str(callback_url),
                status_callback_event='completed',
                status_callback_method='GET',
                url=xml_url,
                to=str(phone_number),
                from_='+1XXX'
            )

    except Campaign.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Campaign Does Not Exist")

    context = {
        'all_campaigns': campaign
    }

    return render(request, "CallCenter/start_campaign.html", context)


def events(request, campaign_id):

    time.sleep(80)

    campaign = Campaign.objects.get(pk=campaign_id)
    campaign.status = 'completed'
    campaign.save()

    account_sid = 'XXX'
    auth_token = 'XXX'
    client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

    sid = request.GET.get('CallSid', default=None)
    detail = client.calls(sid).fetch()

    check = CallHistory.objects.filter(campaign__id=campaign_id)
    if check:
        check = CallHistory.objects.get(campaign__id=campaign_id)

        old_duration = check.call_duration
        new_duration = int(old_duration) + int(detail.duration)
        check.call_duration = int(new_duration)

        old_cost = check.call_cost
        new_cost = float(old_cost) + float((str(detail.price)[1:]))
        check.call_cost = float(new_cost)

        print("Cost:{}\nDuration{}".format(new_cost, new_duration))
        print(str(detail.price)[1:])
        check.save()

    else:
        campaign_history = CallHistory(campaign=campaign, contact=str(detail.to), user=campaign.user,
                                       call_duration=int(detail.duration), call_cost=float((str(detail.price)[1:])))

        campaign_history.save()

    return render(request, "CallCenter/events.html")
```

Comment: use something like celery async function with retry option on

Comment: Did you solve this issue? what's your are using to wait for a call price? could you share your solution? thanks!